# seaborn regplot formatted dates, regression line date cut off, two y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am looking to be able to quickly compare two different datasets and see how they are correlated at specific dates by looking at the two reggression lines.

I have been trying to have to lineplots on different axis which each have a reggression line going from and to a specific date. The date needs to be the same for both plots and I dont want the reggression line to cover all dates on the X axis only custom ones specified. So the regplot needs to display dates and understand that they are dates.

1. format dates such that they will work with regplot as this is not a
   native feature.
2. two y-axis
3. data displayed as lineplots instead of scatterplots
4. regression lines between specific dates and not all of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt find the answer anywhere so I thought I would post it here as it took some time to figure out.

```
#'date': pandas.to_datetime(date),   # pandas datesimport datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


timeLine = ["2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2024-01-01"]

# format data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates': pd.to_datetime(timeLine),
    'datenum': dates.datestr2num(timeLine),
    'y1': [7, 6, 8, 8, 7],
    'y2': [10, 13, 16, 13, 12]
    })

# dates to float
@pyplot.FuncFormatter
def fake_dates(x, pos):
    return dates.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# date range to constrain length of regression line
startDate = '"2020-02-02"'
endDate = '"2023-05-05"'
customDates = 'Dates > ' + startDate + ' and ' + 'Dates < ' + endDate + ''

"""y1"""
plt.ylim(ymin=0, ymax=20)

# regplot
plot = sns.regplot(x='datenum', y='y1', ci=65, scatter=False, line_kws={'linewidth':10}, data=df.query(customDates), color="red")
# original data
sns.lineplot(x='datenum', y='y1', data=df)

"""y2"""
ax2 = plt.twinx()
plt.ylim(ymin=0, ymax=20)

# regplot
x = sns.regplot(x='datenum', y='y2', ax=ax2, ci=65, scatter=False, line_kws={'linewidth':10}, data=df.query(customDates), color="red")
# original data
y= sns.lineplot(x='datenum', y='y2', ax=ax2,  data=df, color="green")

# fake dates - visual
plot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fake_dates)

plt.show()
```

[image]